# Conditionally selecting blocks in MySQL

Tags: mysql

How can I achieve this kind of selecting blocks in MySQL (conditionally)?

```
SELECT * FROM (IF condition THEN SELECT a,b,c FROM tbl1 ELSE SELECT x,y,z FROM tbl2) AS tmp
```

In reality the two SELECT blocks are much more complicated and there is no possibility to join tables.

Comment: is "condition" a field ?

Comment: No. It is not a field.

Comment: pls giva a sample for the condition

Comment: condition is like EXISTS(SELECT * FROM anothertbl)

Comment: @Junior is your condition truly wjether a 3rd table is empty?

Comment: @Shadow, it is a sample for the "condition" to clarify if it is a field or not (as BerndBuffen asked). It is just an example and it can be exactly as you say, to check if 3rd table is empty or not. My challenge is to run two totally different queries and get the result according to a condition and without running both queries.

Comment: Then you cannot do this as a query, you need to write more complex script either as a stored procedure or dynamic sql as in the answer. Since we do not know exactly the condition, it is not possible to tell you which solution would be better for you.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a PREPARED statement like this:

you must change the SELECT for the condition. I have no Infos from you

```
SELECT IF( "condition", 'SELECT a,b,c FROM tbl1 AS tmp' , 'SELECT x,y,z FROM tbl2 AS tmp' ) INTO @thequery
FROM sometable;

SELECT @thequery; -- ONLY for test

PREPARE stmt FROM @thequery;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: it is called synamic sql